# How to split a delimited string in Ruby and convert it to an array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, string, split

I have a string

`"1,2,3,4"`

and I'd like to convert it into an array:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

How?

Comment: "1,2|3;42:4711".scan(/\d+/).map {|i| i.to_i }

Answer (score 435, accepted):

```
>> "1,2,3,4".split(",")
=> ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Or for integers:

```
>> "1,2,3,4".split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Or for later versions of ruby (>= 1.9 - as pointed out by Alex):

```
>> "1,2,3,4".split(",").map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Remember, if you're using >=1.9, you can just use "1,2,3,4".split(',').map(:to_i)

Comment: If you're using active support you can do: map(&:to_i)

Answer (score 31):

`"1,2,3,4".split(",")` as strings

`"1,2,3,4".split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }` as integers

Answer (score 19):

#### For `String Integer` without space as `String`

```
arr = "12345"

arr.split('')

output: ["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

#### For `String Integer` with space as `String`

```
arr = "1 2 3 4 5"

arr.split(' ')

output: ["1","2","3","4","5"]
```

#### For `String Integer` without space as `Integer`

```
arr = "12345"

arr.split('').map(&:to_i)

output: [1,2,3,4,5]
```

#### For String

```
arr = "abc"

arr.split('')

output: ["a","b","c"]
```

**Explanation**:

1. `arr` -> string which you're going to perform any action.
2. `split()` -> is an method, which split the input and store it as array.
3. `''` or `' '` or `','` -> is an value, which is needed to be removed from given string.

Answer (score 2):

```
"12345".each_char.map(&:to_i)
```

`each_char` does basically the same as `split('')`: It splits a string into an array of its characters.

hmmm, I just realize now that in the original question the string contains commas, so my answer is not really helpful ;-(..

Comment: can you edit your answer to explain what you are doing?

Comment: At least for me, it was really helpful because I was exactly looking for a replacement for `"".split('')` into something more _rubyist_

Answer (score 2):

the simplest way to convert a string that has a delimiter like a comma is just to use the split method

```
"1,2,3,4".split(',') # "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

you can find more info on how to use the split method in the [ruby docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/split)

> Divides str into substrings based on a delimiter, returning an array
>   of these substrings.
>
> If pattern is a String, then its contents are used as the delimiter
>   when splitting str. If pattern is a single space, str is split on
>   whitespace, with leading whitespace and runs of contiguous whitespace
>   characters ignored.
>
> If pattern is a Regexp, str is divided where the pattern matches.
>   Whenever the pattern matches a zero-length string, str is split into
>   individual characters. If pattern contains groups, the respective
>   matches will be returned in the array as well.
>
> If pattern is omitted, the value of $; is used. If $; is nil (which is
>   the default), str is split on whitespace as if ` ‘ were specified.
>
> If the limit parameter is omitted, trailing null fields are
>   suppressed. If limit is a positive number, at most that number of
>   fields will be returned (if limit is 1, the entire string is returned
>   as the only entry in an array). If negative, there is no limit to the
>   number of fields returned, and trailing null fields are not
>   suppressed.