# Ruby - How to parse string to array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a string stored in a database like so:

```
images = '[{"id":1,"type":"Image","image_id":"asdf123"},{"id":2,"type":"Image","image_id":"asdf456"},{"id":3,"type":"Image","image_id":"asdf890"}]'
```

And would like to convert it to an array so I can do something like:

```
images.each do |image|
    puts image.image_id
end
```

Is it really just a matter of removing the outer square brackets and then following the procedure from this question [Converting a Ruby String into an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/975769/converting-a-ruby-string-into-an-array) or is there a more direct/elegant method?

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the format in which the database is stored? It is not a matter of removing the outer square brackets.

Comment: @sawa Why isn't it clear? The question states "I have a string stored in a database", it is stored as a string.

Comment: FYI, there is more than one format of database in the world. Also, what you gave is not a valid Ruby string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That format is called [JavaScript Object Notation (JSON)](http://www.json.org/) and can be parsed by a [builtin Ruby library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html):

```ruby
require 'json'

images_str = '[{"id":1,"type":"Image","image_id":"asdf123"},{"id":2,"type":"Image","image_id":"asdf456"},{"id":3,"type":"Image","image_id":"asdf890"}]'

images = JSON.parse(images_str)
images.size           # => 3
images[0].class       # => Hash
images[0]['image_id'] # => "asdf123"

images.each { |x| puts "#{x['id']}: #{x['image_id']}" }
# 1: asdf123
# 2: asdf456
# 3: asdf890
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought, I've been trying to loop through the results of `JSON.parse` with `images.each do |image|` but keep getting `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: @waffl: without seeing your exact code and data it's hard to say why you might see that error; however, my guess is that you are not actually parsing the JSON string you expect so you get a nil value instead of an array.

Comment: you are correct – I was not parsing the correct string, and this works perfectly!